# VBA - Dynamic Copy&Past of a Range

Tags: vba

Can't find the correct syntax for the dynamic range, please help.

- On 'Sheet1' I have a source table range "B2:F50"
- For each row in that table need to test certain condition
- If condition is met THEN copy that table line to a new position,
  on 'Sheet1' Example:

```
FOR I = 1 TO 50  ' I for each Row)
   IF certain cell = x THEN
      'copy that table line entries (not entire row) to a new position
       Range(source I, source-Col).Copy (target I, target-Col)
   END IF
 NEXT I
```

- Basically creating a new table (On same rows, shifted columns) but with only entries
  that meet the condition. Don't want to copy entire rows.
  Many thanks
  Sam

Answer (score 0):

I believe something along these lines should sort out your problem:

```
Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

For i = 2 to 50
    
    If dataWS.Cells(i,1).value = x Then
        
        dataWS.Range(dataWS.Cells(i, 2), dataWS.Cells(i, 5)).Copy Destination:=dataWS.Range(dataWS.Cells(i, 12), dataWS.Cells(i, 15))
        
    End If
    
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks you for the solution. I have tried several ways. Yours works well. Thanks Sam

Comment: Happy to have helped!